# Serving Static Files with Slim Application v3 Using Built In PHP Server

Tags: php, slim

I'm starting a new project using Slim framework. So far it's going decently, everything I'm looking for in a micro framework. I have been away from the PHP world for a while so I am now getting to know the built in PHP web server. The only issue is this: How do I serve my static content?

For reference, here is my project layout:

```
project:
    public folder
        index.php
        static/css/style.css
        templates/index.html .  # I'm using twig (coming from python Flask)
```

My template:

```
<html>
    <link href="{{ base_url() }}/css/agency.css" rel="stylesheet">  
    <!-- other cool layout stuff -->
```

and my index.php (very minimal)

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php'; 
$app = new \Slim\App();      
$app->get('/', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    $response = $this->view->render($response, 'base.html');
    return $response->write("Hello ");    
});
$app->run();
```

When I start the built in php server from the command line, I do this:

```
php -S localhost:8080 -t public public/index.php
```

While this works great, when I try to access my static content, it just returns the rendered base.html file

Please let me know the best way to start this so static content is rendered correctly. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at example #3 in the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Comment: I'd say have a look at example *#4* in the mentioned link in previous comment. For a practical example, have a look at this https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Skeleton/blob/master/public/index.php#L2

Comment: So I just posted an answer. It involves both of what kuh-chan and Nima responded with. I also added a 404 response if the file doesn't exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So based on the documentation as pointed out by kuh-chan and Nima, I expanded it for both Slim purposes, as well as returning a 404 response if the file did not exist.

```
if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli-server') {

    $url  = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $file = __DIR__ . $url['path'];

    // check the file types, only serve standard files
    if (preg_match('/\.(?:png|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|css)$/', $file)) {
        // does the file exist? If so, return it
        if (is_file($file))
            return false;

        // file does not exist. return a 404
        header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 404 Not Found');
        printf('"%s" does not exist', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        return false;
    }
}
```